# Pillow not installed in heroku server

Tags: python, django, heroku

After I include the command "release: python manage.py migrate" in my Procfile I am getting the following error when I push the files to heroku:

```
Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
remote:         HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run 
command "pip install Pillow".
```

Then I added Pillow to my Pipfile:

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true


[packages]

django = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
django-heroku = "*"
django-crispy-forms = "*"
django-multiselectfield = "*"
django-session-timeout = "*"
Pillow = "*"


[requires]

python_version = "3.6"
```

I did run the command "git add Pipfile Pipfile.lock" and pushed to heroku and the error still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I forgot to run the command "pipenv lock" to write the packages to my Pipfile.lock.